# PostGraphile subscription on totalCount with filter ignores decrements

Tags: graphql, graphiql, postgraphile

#### Goal:

Subscribe to a count of Products (from a Postgres DB) scheduled for today with state=NEW

#### The code:

```
subscription getTotalNewProducts {
  orderProducts(
      condition: {state: "NEW"}, 
      filter: {scheduledDate: {greaterThanOrEqualTo: "2020-02-27", lessThan: "2020-02-28"}}) 
    {
      totalCount
    }
}
```

#### The issue:

The totalCount increases whenever I INSERT or UPDATE a Product so it complies to the condition. However, it never decreases when I DELETE or UPDATE a Product to no longer comply to the condition. The problem occurs both in my application and in GraphiQL, so I narrowed it down to the code above.

I use postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter for the filter but removing it did not change the issue.

#### What I found so far:

A workaround in adding nodes to my result. When I add nodes with some arbitrary property, the subscription behaves correctly. Like so:

```
subscription getTotalNewProducts {
  orderProducts(
      condition: {state: "NEW"}, 
      filter: {scheduledDate: {greaterThanOrEqualTo: "2020-02-27", lessThan: "2020-02-28"}})
      {
        totalCount
        nodes {
          productId
        }
      }
}
```

Is there a way to make this work correctly without including the nodes in the result?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, I suggest you file it against the PostGraphile repo.